# How to remove SKU on the product page?

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute

I want to remove the SKU from the product display page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

To remove it just from the view, copy the following file:

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml
```

to your template folder, which should be something like this:

```
app\design\frontend\[your_theme]\theme\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml
```

Then remove the following block of code (should be somewhere around line 36)

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
  <arguments>
    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
    <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
```

And replace it with:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true"/>
```

clear the cache, and the SKU should be removed from the product view.

Comment: In the theme there is no code like above code.

Comment: Yes it is there. Open the given xml file

Comment: <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="fasony-custom-block" after="-">
<arguments>
                   <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">fasony-custom-block</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="fasony-sidebar-banner" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">fasony-banner-sidebar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

Comment: HOw to fix it??

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app/design/frontend/default/your theme/template/catalog/products/view.html`

Just add command line

[image]

:)

Comment: Sir I am working On Magento 2.1

Comment: Then Above Path is not working

Comment: How to use in Luma Theme

Comment: Find view.html path, do as same as what I did.

Comment: It is not in the html file it is in the xml file

Comment: Study magento2 by documentation where is the file "view" and do your customization.

Comment: It is done from me

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file catalog_product_view.xml in your theme

and paste the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

then run following commands to flush the cache

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento cache:clean

Answer (score -4):

1. Go to Admin > Catalog >Attributes > Manage Attributes sets > And remove SKU field

Comment: and move that SKU field to unassigned attributes which is at right section.

Comment: How to remove in Magento 2.1

Comment: yes it is mentioned in my second answer. It will surely work in magento 2.

Comment: I want in the home page that doesnot shows the sku

Comment: It is only shows in the admin section only